# Why aggregations are not possible in HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, hbase

I am wondering why aggregation operations such as **SUM / AVG** are not natively supported by HBase. I got to know that there are several workarounds for achieving the same, but while there are these workarounds, why HBase does not provide it natively. More importantly, please explain why it is not possible to perform these operations concerning the Key-Value data structure used by Hbase and the querying logic behind it.

Comment: There is already an AggregationClient available in HBase 2.x. Do you think this suits you ?

Answer (score 2):

Aggregation operations are natively supported by HBase. [Coprocessors](https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/coprocessor_introduction) allow data to be aggregated quickly and efficiently on region servers, and as @Kris mentioned there is a ready-made [AggregationClient](https://hbase.apache.org/2.0/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/coprocessor/AggregationClient.html) Coprocessor that can perform common aggregations without needing to write and deploy custom code.

For an example ([src](https://www.javatips.net/api/learning-hadoop-master/cdh-hbase-examples/src/com/embracesource/edh/hbase/AggregateTest.java)):

```java
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.setInt("hbase.client.retries.number", 1);
conf.setInt("ipc.client.connect.max.retries", 1);
    
byte[] table = Bytes.toBytes("t");
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("f"), Bytes.toBytes("id"));
ColumnInterpreter<Long, Long> columnInterpreter = new LongStrColumnInterpreter();

AggregationClient aClient = new AggregationClient(conf);
Long rowCount = aClient.min(table, columnInterpreter, scan);
System.out.println("The min value is " + rowCount);
```

Comment: I did get to know about the above-mentioned, but the actual question in my mind is: Was avoiding aggregations in Hbase a choice, or is it a limitation because of its design? Hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Coprocessors are a feature of HBase designed to perform aggregations. You can use `AggregationClient` to perform aggregations in only a few lines of code and they will be very fast because computation takes place on each region server. https://www.javatips.net/api/learning-hadoop-master/cdh-hbase-examples/src/com/embracesource/edh/hbase/AggregateTest.java